# I can't read file using RNFS using phasset taken from RNCameraRoll

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, phasset, react-native-fs

I'm trying to validate the file size of the image selected from CameraRoll in React Native. My code works in Android but it doesn't work in IOS because RNFS.readFile does not support PHASSETS. Is there any other way to validate the file size of an image in react native?

I've also tried using copyAssetsFileIOS of RNFS

```
RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(path, RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath, 0, 0)
        .then(res => console.log('RES: ', res))
        .catch(err => console.log('ERROR: ', err));
```

I've also tried converting the PHASSET into ALASSET

```
path = `assets-library://asset/asset.${ext}?id=${path.substr(9)}&ext=${ext}`;
```

Here is my code that works in Android but not in IOS

```
RNFS.readFile(path, 'base64')
      .then(res => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const str = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? base64.decode(res) : atob(res);
        const fileSize = str.length;
        if (fileSize < 3000000)
          this.setState({
            imageSource: source,
            hasExceededLimit: false,
          });
        else this.setState({ hasExceededLimit: true });
      })
      .catch(() => this.setState({ hasExceededLimit: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS is sandboxed, which means you have no direct read/write access to any files outside your App Bundle.
To access photos/videos from the iOS Photo-Library please use the methods from the Photos-Framework.

Comment: Thanks but how do I use Photos-Framework in React Native?